# Add v-tooltip to v-treeview in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, treeview, tooltip, vuetify.js

How do we add tooltip to each node of tree in vuetify tree component. 
Adding a v-tooltip to tree component adds a tooltip to the component itself not each of its nodes.

```
<v-tooltip bottom slot="activator">
    <v-treeview
        v-model="tree"
        :items="items"
        slot="activator"
    >
    </v-treeview>
    <span>Top tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

A pending pull request solves the problem. This provides a slot for label along with append and prepend

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/5567